# Hiding bar in stacked bar chart on click on label in Apexcharts angular

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I'm using Apexcharts in my angular application. I have plotted a stacked bar chart. The issue is one of the bar have large amount of number and it outgrow every other bars in the chart and the stacks in the smaller bars are not visible. So I'm trying to implement an option to hide the desired bar on clicking on the label of that particular bar.

I couldn't find any method to implement the same and I'm stuck on this.
Thanks in advance.